# Field aggregation not summing correctly based on join to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the below query where I am trying to calculate a percentage based on the SUM of `G.MERCHANDISE_AMT` divided by the SUM of `D.MERCHANDISE_AMT`. The `PO_ID` in this table contains 2 line numbers, and each line number has 2 distributions, for a total of 4 rows, and I am getting the SUM of the `D.MERCHANDISE_AMT` accross all 4 rows. Please note that `G.MERCHANDISE_AMT` is a field in these two tables, `PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D` and `PS_DISTRIB_LINE G`

```
SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), A.VENDOR_ID,
A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS 'TOTAL_VCHR_AMT', NULLIF((SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) / SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT)),0) AS 'Threshold' , E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID AS 'REQUESTOR', H.ROLEUSER_SUPR

FROM PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D 
INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = C.PO_ID AND C.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR
INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.PO_ID = C.PO_ID
INNER JOIN  PS_DEPT_TBL E ON  E.DEPTID = D.DEPTID AND E.SETID = D.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL 
INNER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE G ON  G.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND G.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H ON H.ROLEUSER = E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID  

WHERE 
  A.PO_TYPE IN ('AGR','BO')
  AND A.PO_STATUS IN ('A','D','O')
  AND D.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
  AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
  AND E.EFFDT =  (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
  WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
  AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
  AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))

GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.PO_ID, A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID, H.ROLEUSER_SUPR  

HAVING (SUM(F.MERCHANDISE_AMT) / SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT)) > .80   

ORDER BY PO_ID
```

The problem is that the data from `PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D` is being duplicated twice for each row, because of the join to `PS_DISTRIB_LINE G`.

`PS_DISTRIB_LINE G` itself contains 10 rows for the same PO, because the distributions are across multiple VOUCHER_IDs. From `PS_DISTRIB_LINE G` I need to get the SUM of `G.MERCHANDISE_AMT` from all 10 rows (denominator), however the SUM on the numerator, (FROM `PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D`) `D.MERCHANDISE_AMT` needs to be based on the 4 rows for that `PO_ID`.

Here is another way of looking at it:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D
WHERE PO_ID = 'J010000185'
AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
```

Results in the following data for `PO_ID 'J010000185'`

```
BUSINESS_UNIT   PO_ID        LINE_NBR   SCHED_NBR   DST_ACCT_TYPE   QTY_PO      DISTRIB_LINE_NUM    CURRENCY_CD   MERCHANDISE_AMT
50000           J010000185   1          1           DST             0.6000      1                   USD           39240.000
50000           J010000185   1          1           DST             0.4000      2                   USD           26160.000
50000           J010000185   2          1           DST             0.5000      1                   USD           7000.000
50000           J010000185   2          1           DST             0.5000      2                   USD           7000.000
```

So the SUM of D.MERCHANDISE_AMT for the above results in 79,400 (This should be the amount going into the denominator of `NULLIF((SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) / SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT)),0) AS 'Threshold'`.

If I query for this same PO_ID in `PS_DISTRIB_LINE G` with the following query, these are the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE
WHERE PO_ID = 'J010000185'
AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'

BUSINESS_UNIT   PO_ID         VOUCHER_ID    VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    DISTRIB_LINE_NUM    BUSINESS_UNIT_GL    MONETARY_AMOUNT
50000           J010000185    00026741      2                   1                   11000               9810.000
50000           J010000185    00026741      2                   2                   41000               6540.000
50000           J010000185    00026921      2                   1                   11000               1774.130
50000           J010000185    00026921      2                   2                   41000               1774.130
50000           J010000185    00026922      2                   1                   11000               9810.000
50000           J010000185    00026922      2                   2                   41000               6540.000
50000           J010000185    00033438      2                   1                   11000               2128.280
50000           J010000185    00033438      2                   2                   41000               2128.280
50000           J010000185    00033440      2                   1                   11000               9810.000
50000           J010000185    00033440      2                   2                   41000               6540.000
```

Ths SUM of `MERCHANDISE_AMT` from `PS_DISTRIB_LINE G` is 56854.82 , so the calculation on the expression `NULLIF((SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) / SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT)),0) AS 'Threshold'` should result in the following:

56845.82 / 79,400 = .7194

However because `PS_DISTRIB_LINE` contains more rows than `PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB` (10 vs 4 in this example) for the same PO_ID, the calculated SUM on `PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB` is getting skewed (higher than it should be)

If I query just these two tables, using their common joins, you can see the issue occuring and the the `SUM` of `D.MERCHANDISE_AMT` (1st Column) will be incorrect:

```
SELECT D.MERCHANDISE_AMT, G.MERCHANDISE_AMT, D.MERCHANDISE_AMT, G.MERCHANDISE_AMT, D.BUSINESS_UNIT, G.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, G.PO_ID, D.LINE_NBR, G.LINE_NBR, D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM, G.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
FROM PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D
INNER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE G ON  G.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND G.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
WHERE D.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'

MERCHANDISE_AMT MERCHANDISE_AMT   BUSINESS_UNIT  BUSINESS_UNIT  PO_ID       PO_ID        LINE_NBR   LINE_NBR    DISTRIB_LINE_NUM    DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
39240.000       9810.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           1                   1
39240.000       9810.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           1                   1
39240.000       9810.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           1                   1
26160.000       6540.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           2                   2
26160.000       6540.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           2                   2
26160.000       6540.000          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   1          1           2                   2
7000.000        2128.280          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   2          2           1                   1
7000.000        1774.130          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   2          2           2                   2
7000.000        1774.130          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   2          2           1                   1
7000.000        2128.280          50000          50000          J010000185  J010000185   2          2           2                   2
```

I posted CREATE TABLE scripts here as additional reference:
https://pastebin.com/rUbRCEj5

What can be done to overcome this?

**3/26 EDIT:**

I created a CTE, with the 2 seperate inner queries being joined in the final select, however I want to group on `(E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID ) AS 'REQUESTOR' but it is not grouping that way. Do I have to modify the inner queries Group By's to do this?

```
        WITH CTE AS

        (SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) AS 'PO_DT', A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.LINE_NBR, D.SCHED_NBR, D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM,       
          SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS 'SUM_MERCH',  E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID AS 'REQUESTOR', H.ROLEUSER_SUPR
        FROM PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D 
        INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = C.PO_ID AND C.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR
        INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.PO_ID = C.PO_ID
        INNER JOIN  PS_DEPT_TBL E ON  E.DEPTID = D.DEPTID AND E.SETID = D.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL 
         --LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER_LINE F ON F.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND F.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND F.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND F.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR
        INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H ON H.ROLEUSER = E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID     
        WHERE 
            A.PO_TYPE IN ('AGR','BO')
            AND A.PO_STATUS IN ('A','D','O')
            --AND D.MERCHANDISE_AMT <> 0.00
            --AND Threshold > .80
            AND D.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
            AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
            AND E.EFFDT =  (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
                WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
                  AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
                  AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))
        GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.PO_ID, A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID , H.ROLEUSER_SUPR, D.LINE_NBR, D.SCHED_NBR, D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM  )
        --HAVING (SUM(F.MERCHANDISE_AMT) / SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT)) > .80      --, F.MERCHANDISE_AMT, D.MERCHANDISE_AMT --,  C.LINE_NBR, D.QTY_PO, D.MERCHANDISE_AMT, D.DEPTID   

        , CTE2 AS (SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) AS 'PO_DT', A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, G.DEPTID, H.ROLEUSER_SUPR, SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS 'SUM_MERCH' , G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO, G.LINE_NBR, G.SCHED_NBR, G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM
           FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE G
           INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C ON  G.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.PO_ID = C.PO_ID AND C.LINE_NBR = G.LINE_NBR
           INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.PO_ID = C.PO_ID
           INNER JOIN  PS_DEPT_TBL E ON  E.DEPTID = G.DEPTID AND E.SETID = G.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL 
           INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H ON H.ROLEUSER = E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID  
           WHERE G.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
           AND G.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
           AND E.EFFDT =  (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
                WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
                  AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
                  AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))
           GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.PO_ID, A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)), A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, G.DEPTID,  H.ROLEUSER_SUPR,G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO, G.LINE_NBR, G.SCHED_NBR, G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM )--E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID   )

        SELECT DISTINCT D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.PO_DT,121)), D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR, NULLIF((G.SUM_MERCH / D.SUM_MERCH),0) AS 'Threshold'
        FROM CTE D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 G ON G.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND G.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
        GROUP BY D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.PO_DT,121)), D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR
```

**3/27 EDIT:**

These are the changes I have made thus far, and I think the trouble is occuring on the final block of select (derived) statements. I commented out the Group By as it doesn't appear that it's needed there, but I am getting syntax errors. I believe alias needs to be added, but I have added these and are still getting the error.

```
 WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) AS 'PO_DT', A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, --, D.LINE_NBR
    --, D.SCHED_NBR, 
    --D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM,       
      SUM(D.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS 'PO_SUM_MERCH_AMT',  E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID AS 'REQUESTOR', H.ROLEUSER_SUPR
    FROM PS_PO_LINE_DISTRIB D 
    INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.PO_ID = C.PO_ID AND C.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR
    INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.PO_ID = C.PO_ID
    INNER JOIN  PS_DEPT_TBL E ON  E.DEPTID = D.DEPTID AND E.SETID = D.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL 
    INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H ON H.ROLEUSER = E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID     
    WHERE 
        A.PO_TYPE IN ('AGR','BO')
        AND A.PO_STATUS IN ('A','D','O')
        AND D.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
        AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
        AND E.EFFDT =  (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
            WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
              AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
              AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))  
        GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) , A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID , H.ROLEUSER_SUPR      )


    , CTE2 AS (SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) AS 'PO_DT', A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, G.DEPTID , H.ROLEUSER_SUPR,
       SUM(G.MERCHANDISE_AMT) AS 'SUM_MERCH_AMT', G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO --, G.SCHED_NBR, G.LINE_NBR, G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM, G.VOUCHER_ID, G.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, G.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
       FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE G
       INNER JOIN  PS_PO_LINE C ON  G.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND G.PO_ID = C.PO_ID AND C.LINE_NBR = G.LINE_NBR
       INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR A ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND A.PO_ID = C.PO_ID
       INNER JOIN  PS_DEPT_TBL E ON  E.DEPTID = G.DEPTID AND E.SETID = G.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL 
       INNER JOIN PS_ROLEXLATOPR H ON H.ROLEUSER = E.SETID + '_' +   E.DEPTID  
       WHERE G.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
       AND G.PO_ID = 'J010000185'
       AND E.EFFDT =  (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_DEPT_TBL A_ED
            WHERE E.SETID = A_ED.SETID
              AND E.DEPTID = A_ED.DEPTID
              AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
      GROUP BY A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.PO_ID,  A.PO_TYPE, A.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.PO_DT,121)) , A.VENDOR_SETID, A.VENDOR_ID, A.BUYER_ID, G.DEPTID,
        G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO, H.ROLEUSER_SUPR )

    Select REQUESTOR, BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, PO_TYPE, PO_STATUS, PO_DT, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, BUYER_ID, DEPTID, ROLEUSER_SUPR, NULLIF((SUM_MERCHA / SUM_MERCHB),0) AS 'Threshold' from
    (
    Select REQUESTOR, BUSINESS_UNIT, PO_ID, PO_TYPE, PO_STATUS, PO_DT, VENDOR_SETID, VENDOR_ID, BUYER_ID, DEPTID, ROLEUSER_SUPR, SUM(SUM_MERCHA) as SUM_MERCHA, SUM(SUM_MERCHB) as SUM_MERCHB from (
    SELECT  D.REQUESTOR, D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, (CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.PO_DT,121)) as PO_DT, D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR, G.MERCHANDISE_AMT as SUM_MERCHA,  D.MERCHANDISE_AMT as SUM_MERCHB
    FROM CTE D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE2 G ON G.PO_ID = D.PO_ID AND G.BUSINESS_UNIT_PO = D.BUSINESS_UNIT  AND G.SCHED_NBR = D.SCHED_NBR AND G.LINE_NBR = D.LINE_NBR AND G.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM = D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM)
    --Group by D.REQUESTOR, D.BUSINESS_UNIT, D.PO_ID, D.PO_TYPE, D.PO_STATUS, PO_DT, D.VENDOR_SETID, D.VENDOR_ID, D.BUYER_ID, D.DEPTID, D.ROLEUSER_SUPR) E ) F
```

Comment: You'd better simplify your tables for the question and leave only relevant columns. The general approach is to split your query into three parts. 1. Calculate one set of sums grouping by one set of columns. 2. Calculate second set of sums grouping by another set of columns. 3. Join two previous sets together to calculate the ratio. You can use explicit temp tables or CTEs to make the query readable.

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't a way to get a distinct count for just one column?

Comment: As you suggested, I split this into three parts, into a CTE. However in the final select I am trying to summarize the data but getting syntax errors: Please see: https://pastebin.com/9KeggB8k

Comment: It is unlikely that somebody would read through your complex queries. That's why I suggested to simplify the underlying tables and provide an example with just one or two tables and few columns. I didn't try to read your long queries. Just a general note, the first CTE should have `GROUP BY` to calculate, say, denominator values. The second CTE should have (a possibly different) `GROUP BY` to calculate numerator values. The final JOIN should not have any `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`, it should calculate the ratios.